# Set Equal height on window resize not working

Tags: jquery, height

I able to set equal height of all item in a row using jQuery code. .  but IDK why its not working on window resize. this is very important for tab and mobile view . Here is my code

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
  function eq_height(){  
  var content = $('div.item');

    content.each(function() {
   var maxheight = 0;
        if(maxheight < $(this).siblings().outerHeight()){
              maxheight = $(this).siblings().outerHeight()
         $(this).siblings().height(maxheight)
        };
  });
}
eq_height();

$(window).resize(eq_height); //this part is not working. 


});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
.wrapper .item {
    display: inline-flex;
    max-width: 30%;
    background: #ddd;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">Lorm ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum maiores repellendus explicabo voluptatum minima similique soluta magnam aperiam aliquid ipsam commodi nisi. explicabo voluptatum minima similique soluta magnam aperiam aliquid ipsam commodi nisi</div>
<div class="item">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur, accusamus?</div>
<div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi ratione nisi cupiditate officiis! Ut, labore?</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="item">Lorm ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum maiores repellendus explicabo voluptatum minima</div>
<div class="item">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur, accusamus?</div>
<div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi ratione nisi cdupiditate officiis! Ut, labore?</div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/maruf_sarkar/pen/BaWERjv)
Thanks in advance

Comment: What result do you want to get? That all item are the same height?

Comment: I want to get items are in same height  in row. . its okay now but not working in window resize 
https://codepen.io/maruf_sarkar/pen/BaWERjv

Comment: I didn't understand your goal exactly but you should remove this line: $(document).ready(eq_height); since you're already calling that function when the page loads ( eq_height(); ) Also if you're declaring maxheight=0 the "if" contition will always be true, so you don't need it either. Also, when the window resizes you're not making any changes, so how do you expect the elements to change?

Comment: I am sorry that I couldn’t explain clearly... 
My goal is to set equal height of all items in row, as currently it is.  But for phone and tablet user may rotate device to landscape to portrait or so on... then I want to run same function agian so it will be equal. 

NOTE: I cant use css grid there.. there are lots of other elements too . Need Js solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were after?

```
let maxheight = 0
content.each(function() {
  maxheight = Math.max(maxheight, $(this).height())
});
$('div.item').css('height', maxheight + "px")
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  function eq_height() {
    var content = $('div.item');
    let maxheight = 0
    content.each(function() {
      maxheight = Math.max(maxheight, $(this).height())
    });
    //console.log(maxheight)
    $('div.item').css('height', maxheight + "px")
  }
  eq_height();

  $(window).resize(eq_height);
  $(document).ready(eq_height);

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.wrapper .item {
  display: inline-flex;
  max-width: 30%;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">Lorm ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum maiores repellendus explicabo voluptatum minima similique soluta magnam aperiam aliquid ipsam commodi nisi. explicabo voluptatum minima similique soluta magnam aperiam aliquid ipsam commodi
    nisi
  </div>
  <div class="item">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur, accusamus?</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi ratione nisi cupiditate officiis! Ut, labore?</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="item">Lorm ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum maiores repellendus explicabo voluptatum minima</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur, accusamus?</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi ratione nisi cdupiditate officiis! Ut, labore?</div>
</div>
```